# two distributed rendering contexts - synchronization

Tags: c++, opengl, distributed-system

I have a logic application which increment an integer counter. That counter should be rendered by two independent applications. Each graphics application creates a window with the opengl context. A logic application communicates with the graphics applications through a network and there may be a few milliseconds lag between sending an actual counter value:

```
for(const auto& graphicsAppHandle: graphicsApps)
{
    graphicsAppHandle.updateCounter(counter);
}
```

I want to synchronize a counter rendering. How to achieve that ?

Comment: What you describe sounds for me like "software genlock". In the past, where we had these big Onyx racks there was a H/W genlock feature. We used it to sync. 5 IR2 boards for driving a 5-sided cave. The team at TU Braunschweig used Linux PCs instead and I believe the did sync. using network (UDP) but I'm not sure whether they had a genlock.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I googled "opengl software genlock" and found e.g. [WinSGL: Software Genlocking for Cost-Effective Display Synchronization under Microsoft Windows](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221357176_WinSGL_Software_Genlocking_for_Cost-Effective_Display_Synchronization_under_Microsoft_Windows). Not sure whether this helps but may be at least some new key words to google yourself...

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-trivial task. There are many facets to this problem and the solution will vary greatly with your precise timing requirements, and hardware and software environment. I've worked with people who devoted perhaps 40% of their full-time job to handling image synchronization across multiple image generation devices.

Nvidia's Quadro line of graphic cards [supports synchronization](http://www.nvidia.ca/object/IO_10794.html) through a common master signal source. Note that you'll have to pay much more for your graphics cards than you're probably used to if you go with Quadros.

Search terms related to what you want to do are "frame lock" and "genlock".